# call synchronize method for JsonArrayRequest using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

How can i  call synchronize method for JsonArrayRequest using volley ? i want to synchronize my data within a specific time from server
I know how to get data from server using volley but i need a method something like that which keep getting data from server within a specific time using volley, Thanks

Comment: Check if this can help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651343/android-volley-how-to-synchronize-data-from-listener-onrespone-for-to-use-it-o

Comment: didn't help? i want method which sync data from server continously

Comment: run Intent service using timer or scheduler

Comment: can you brief me more how i can do this param